# How to do absolute addressing in cells with two-letter column identifiers using $ in the formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I know how to do absolute addressing in Excel cell reference by using the **$** prefix for single-letter cell references (e.g., $A$5, etc.).  But I cannot lock the cells with double-letter columns, i.e., $AB$5 or $AA5, etc.

Can somebody tell me how to use **$** prefix in Excel formulas for two-letter cell references?

Comment: I've given you an answer, but I get the feeling you are having a specific issue... if you can elaborate, you'll get a less generic answer.

Comment: You do it correctly: `$AB$5`. A prefix before column identifier and a prefix before row identifier. Different possible reference "locks": `$AB5`, `AB$5`.

Comment: As Stese commented, you are doing it exactly the right way.  You can anchor the column and/or the row.  The column or row identifier can be longer than one character, so anchoring column AB is like anchoring row 125; the column or row identifier doesn't affect it.  If that's not working for you, something is wrong.  To figure out what the problem and solution are, we'll need to know exactly what symptoms you're experiencing and the formulas.

Answer (score 2):

As they are simply cell references, the usage does not change between single and double letter cells.